# What is the difference between @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) and @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I was using `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` for my junit test with mockito. But now I am working with spring-boot and JUnit 5.
What's the difference between the two annotations ? 
Can I use only `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` to mock my objects ?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

**When involving Spring**:

If you want to use Spring test framework features in your tests like for example `@MockBean`, then you have to use `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`. It replaces the deprecated JUnit4 `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`

**When NOT involving Spring**:

If you just want to involve Mockito and don't have to involve Spring, for example,  when you just want to use the `@Mock` / `@InjectMocks` annotations, then you want to use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`, as it doesn't load in a bunch of unneeded Spring stuff. It replaces the deprecated JUnit4 `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`.

**To answer your question**:

Yes you can just use `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`, but if you're not involving Spring test framework features in your tests, then you probably want to just use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`.